# Saving and Retrieving Image Makes App Working Slowly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

I save picture from `UIImagePicker` this way:

Save picture in file and then I save path to the fail in NSUserDefaults and then in another class I retrieve the picture by this saved path.

**Code:**

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{    
    ideaImage.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)saveIdea_alt
{
    [self performSelector: @selector(saveIdea)  withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
-(void)saveIdea
{
    UIImage *ideaPhoto = ideaImage.image;

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ideaPhoto);

    NSString* imageName = @"MyImage.png";

    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];



    NSArray *arrayKeys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ideaName",@"ideaCost",@"ideaNote", @"ideaImage", nil];
    NSArray *arrayObjects = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:ideaName.text,ideaCost.text,ideaNote.text,fullPathToFile ,  nil];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:arrayObjects forKeys:arrayKeys];
    NSMutableArray *ideasArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ideasArray"]];

    [ideasArray addObject:dictionary];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:ideasArray forKey:@"ideasArray"];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

However, after that my app becomes slow and it saves and loads images slowly. What I do wrong ?

I don't really want to use **Core Data** because I already save all others properties of idea in `NSUserDefaults` (like cost, name, color and etc.)

Comment: because at one time u r saving one image it should not be problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting values in `NSUserDefaults`,Just write this line :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
[self performSelectorInBackground: @selector(saveIdea)  withObject:nil];
```

instead of

```
[self performSelector: @selector(saveIdea)  withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```